# Android Studio Git push to bitbucket is rejected

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, pull

I have created a repo in Bitbucket without README file but with .gitignore file and that's all. The repo has no other files but .gitignore, and I am trying to push files from my Android Studio but it always gets rejected.
I know that this question has been asked before, but I have done everything people have said and it still not working.
Here is what I did:

1- I have done my initial commit on Android Studio

2- I have tried to push to my Bitbucket repo

3- I got the rejection

4- I have tried to pull and then push

5- I got an error about unrelated histories because of conflicts in .gitignore file, so I have renamed on Bitbucket (maybe it is not helpful at all, I don't know, I am just a beginner)

6- I tried to enable related histories, but it didn't work for some reason

7- I deleted the project on Android Studio, created a new one and did all the steps again and still doesn't work

Now I really need your help
Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try `git reset --hard origin/master`, may run `git fetch origin` first. Don't forget to backup your changes

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have run both commands, after that push has worked with no problems. But I didn't understand what has been done, and why a lot of things have been deleted? fortunately, I didn't have anything important, but how can I backup things before doing these two steps again and push them all together to Bitbucket?@to

Comment: ... @ToànNguyễnHải

Comment: u can use git stash. read more https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git fetch origin` and then `git reset --hard origin/master` I was able to solve the problem.
After running these commands a lot of files in the project will be deleted, so before running these two commands, I copied everything in the project and pasted somewhere else, and then added externally all files from the project I have copied to the project with missing files.
It will ask if the same files should be replaced or merged, and then the project will have all its necessary files.
Now we have to make a commit with all files we have added, just like an initial commit. After that, a push to Bitbucket repo should work with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is probably late, there's no need to run any commands. When you create the repo on bitbucket, make sure you don't create any files ( even the recommended onces, i.e No Read Me files...nothing), do you initial commits on android studio then add the bitbucket remote..., authenticate and push, it should work fine.